# How to filter a List of Character Vectors in R?

Tags: r, list, vector, readxl

I'm starting to go round in circles. I feel I have searched online thoroughly but suspect I can't see the wood for the trees now after a few days of coming back to this problem.

I am looking to scrape multiple sets of data from thousands of excel files on a company SharePoint. I have been able to scrape successfully using readxl.

```
library(readxl)
library(data.table)
library(XLConnect)

root_URL <- '//companyname.office.abc.com/sites/thesite/thefolder')
folder.list <- list.dirs(root_URL)
file.list <- list.files(folder.list, pattern = "*.(xlsx|XLSX|xls|XLS|xlsm|XLSM|xlsb|XLSB)$",full.names = T,include.dirs = T)
```

Which results in a nice list of all the files I potentially required to scrape from. I have successfully pulled the data I need from the specific tab ("Address") from the 3rd, 4th and 5th files in my list using the following code.

```
ex.list <- file.list[3:5]
ex.list <- setNames(ex.list, ex.list)

df.list <- lapply(ex.list, read_excel, sheet = 'Address' )

df.list <- Map(function(df, name) {
  df$source_name <- name
  df
}, df.list, names(df.list))
df <- rbindlist(df.list, idcol = "id")
write.csv(df,"testdata1.csv")
```

The problem I have run into is the 1st, 2nd (and other files) do not have a tab called "Address" and I need to exclude these files from my file.list but because this is a list of character vectors I'm struggling to filter the list to exclude when a file doesn't contain a tab called "Address"

I have used lappy with the following result, and have even tried sapply (also shared) but am now struggling to write the conditional statement. Feeling very close but so very far away.

```
> aa <- lapply(ex.list, excel_sheets)
> aa
[[1]]
[1] "NODE SIDE A" "NODE SIDE B" "LMA"         "BASE"        "TUBE"        "Notes"      

[[2]]
[1] "NODE SIDE A" "LMA"         "BASE"        "TUBE"        "Notes"      

[[3]]
[1] "Equipment-Details" "Address"           "Drop Down Values"  "Validation Status" "EquipMaster"      

[[4]]
[1] "Equipment-Details" "Address"           "Drop Down Values"  "Validation Status" "EquipMaster"      

[[5]]
[1] "Equipment-Details" "Address"           "Drop Down Values"  "Validation Status" "EquipMaster"  

> bb <- sapply(ex.list, excel_sheets)
> bb
$'//companyname.office.abc.com/sites/thesite/thefolder/subfolder/file1.xls`
[1] "NODE SIDE A" "NODE SIDE B" "LMA"         "BASE"        "TUBE"        "Notes"      

$`//companyname.office.abc.com/sites/thesite/thefolder/subfolder/file2.xls`
[1] "NODE SIDE A" "LMA"         "BASE"        "TUBE"        "Notes"      

$`//companyname.office.abc.com/sites/thesite/thefolder/subfolder/file3.xls`
[1] "Equipment-Details" "Address"           "Drop Down Values"  "Validation Status" "EquipMaster"      

$`//companyname.office.abc.com/sites/thesite/thefolder/subfolder/file4.xls`
[1] "Equipment-Details" "Address"           "Drop Down Values"  "Validation Status" "EquipMaster"      

$`//companyname.office.abc.com/sites/thesite/thefolder/subfolder/file5.xls`
[1] "Equipment-Details" "Address"           "Drop Down Values"  "Validation Status" "EquipMaster"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
library(readxl)
df.list <- lapply(ex.list, function(x) 
  if ("Address" %in% excel_sheets(x)) read_excel(x,sheet = 'Address')
  else NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading in all files you could filter the list using

```
aa <- list(c("A", "B", "C"),
           c("A", "B", "Address"),
           c("A", "B", "Address"),
           c("A", "B", "C"))

aa[grep(pattern = "Address", aa)]
```

Comment: @Martin_Schmelzer. This worked for me fine, but unable to up vote it currently. Many Thanks.